# Sliding a tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, slide

How do I slide all the content in the table view and update the table view with new content, i am working on a project just like google drive IOS app, where when u click on a folder, the old content slides to left and the new content slides in from the right, does anybody have any idea about this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(toAdd, withRowAnimation: animateLeft ? .Right : .Left)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(toDelete, withRowAnimation: animateLeft ? .Left : .Right)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

If you are going to remove all of the data then the toDelete variable is an array of indexPaths 0 through currentContent.count. The toAdd variable is an array of indexPaths 0 through newContent.count. animateLeft is a boolean of which way you want to animate your content

Comment: WOW, seriously i have no idea about what u r talking, it is not because u are not clear it is because i am a newbie in swift, is there any example project on the net anywhere for me to refer?

Comment: ok, finally, i got my head around the way it is supposed to be done, but i am still not sure how to get toAdd and toDelete values using an array of objects, any help @Sam

Comment: Nice, ty, i figured it out by myself to how to get the details and call inserting and deleting, i am just amused how easy it is to build an app in swift, with all this in built features, no wonder, ios app comes first then comes android, thanks for your help homies.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it in this way:
Customize a cell which contains the left content and right content, in normal, it shows the left content, when user clicks, the cell make a animation of position, which is slide from left to right.
Does it works for your goal?

Comment: Is there any example project on the net anywhere for me to refer?